# Convert 1M to 1,000,000 in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of numbers in the format x.x M and would like to convert them to x,x00,000.

For example if cell A1 = 3.3M, then cell B1 would display = 3,300,000

I've pieced together this formula, but with no luck...

`=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("M",A1)),1000000,0)`

Thanks for the help

Comment: are they all `#.#M` or can it be `#.#K` or `#.#` or `#.#B`?

Comment: and what does not work with the formula you provided?  It looks like it should.

Comment: you formula is going to convert any number without the M designation to 0.  Is that the intent or if an entry does not have an M do you want to retain the number?

Comment: They are a mix of #.#K and #.#M, but I was just focusing on the M's first. This formula just displays "#Value!" for an error in value. Not sure what's causing it

Comment: My guess then is that you have unprintable characters after the value like a space.  What does `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)` return?

Comment: I would prefer to retain the number, how do I change that? Thanks

Comment: you probably have a space after the M.  you can fixt this by by using TRIM.  `=LEFT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-1)*IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("M",A1)),1000000,1)`

Comment: That is it, there's a space after the M. TRIM worked, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a space or a non printing character of some sort after the M.  You can remove the space by using the TRIM function.

In order to retain the number if it does not have an M, change the last 0 of the if to 1.

```
=LEFT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-1)*IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("M",A1)),1000000,1)
```

Alternatively you could change the first part to a substitution

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"M","")*IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("M",A1)),1000000,1)
```

Having said that bit about the 1, it will still return an error if you have a K.  I personally prefer Scott Craner's method for dealing with the K and M.  However a clunky alternative would be a nested IF as follows:

```
=LEFT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-1)*10^IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("M",A1)),6,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("K",A1)),3,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-1)*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(TRIM(A1)),{"K","M"},0)*3),A1)
```

If `B` is also used add it to the array in the match.

[image]

Comment: nice handling of the k and M values